# rails Can not load a installed Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have installed the gem : oauth2

I can load it in irb:

```
$ irb -rubygems
irb(main):001:0> require 'oauth2'
=> true
```

I have :

```
require 'rubygems'
```

in my code

and have set RUBYOPT :

```
export RUBYOPT=rubygems
```

while I still get the error:

```
LoadError in XXXController#login    
no such file to load -- oauth2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify the gem as a dependency in Rails?
If you are using Rails 3, make sure the gem is listed in your `Gemfile` and you successfully executed the command `$ bundle install`.

Comment: Hey, I have a similar problem with a gem which occurs sometimes.The gem is in downloaded form inside the vendor/plugins directory. I have also mentioned it in the config.plugins inside environment.rb. Bundle wont work in my case. How do i solve the issue?